# Trying to understand why the Space Complexity of searching through a grid using BFS is O(m * n), where m is no. of rows and n is no. of cols

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, space-complexity

I am trying to understand the space complexity of using BFS in a grid. When we start on a cell in a grid of m * n dimensions, we could go either up, right, down and left.

My understanding is the Space Complexity should be O(m + n) if we start somewhere in the middle. If we start in one of the 4 corners it should be O(min(m, n)). So overall it could be O(m + n) in the worst case given we don't know where to start.

I tried to test on my local by starting on all of the cells individually in a grid and calculate the max size of the queue and understand the Space Complexity.

My test code:

```
class Solution {

    int max = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        int rows = 200, cols = 200;
        int[][] grid = new int[rows][cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                solution.initializeGrid(grid, rows, cols);
                solution.processGrid(grid, rows, cols, i, j);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Highest queue size is " + solution.max);
    }

    private void initializeGrid(int[][] grid, int rows, int cols) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void processGrid(int[][] grid, int rows, int cols, int row, int col) {
        Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        int[] childrenRows = new int[]{-1, 0, 1, 0};
        int[] childrenCols = new int[]{0, 1, 0, -1};

        queue.add(new int[]{row, col});
        grid[row][col] = 0;

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            max = Math.max(max, queue.size());

            int[] parent = queue.poll();
            int pr = parent[0], pc = parent[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int cr = pr + childrenRows[i], cc = pc + childrenCols[i];

                if (cr >= 0 && cr < rows && cc >= 0 && cc < cols && grid[cr][cc] == 1) {
                    queue.add(new int[]{cr, cc});
                    grid[cr][cc] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output for the given input of m = 200, n = 200 is

```
The highest queue size is 399. This value proportional to O(m + n)
```

I know this is not the right way to calculate Space Complexity but I want to the know exact space used by the queue and if it's proportional to O(m * n) or not.

I tried with other larger inputs. Still, the Space Complexity is O(m + n).

Am I missing something here? Could someone please help me to understand the logic?

Comment: You are measuring the size of the queue which is not the complexity?

Comment: The reason am measuring the size of the queue is because it's gives the amount of space that is being used. I understand that it's not the right way to calculate Space Complexity but ideally it should tell me if the amount of space used is proportional to the O(m * n) or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are focusing on the max queue size, but you hit the `O(m * n)` space right at the beginning of your algorithm:

```
boolean[][] visited = new boolean[rows][cols]
```

You've just allocated `O(m * n)` space!

In generic BFS, you have to keep track of all visited states, so the space bound cannot be lower than the total number of states.

---

That being said `O(m * n)` is only valid when the grid can be complex. If it's just a full grid of size m x n, you can optimize the algorithm to make it `O(m + n)` space -- you don't need to keep the whole history of visited cells in memory.

Comment: I agree that the Space Complexity (SC) is O(m * n) when I track the state with a separate grid. I edited my program not to use the visited grid but make change to the original grid itself and initialize the grid every time we calculate the size. Could you please let me know if the SC is still O(m * n) now?

Comment: Ah, I just edited mine in parallel. No if we assume grid is just a full m x n, you can do it in O(m + n).

Comment: But your implementation is still O(m*n). You're modifying the `grid` array of arrays, which is m x n. That doesn't count. You can optimize to do it without any modification.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by optimize without any modification? Without changing the grid value for a particular cell how would I know which cell is already seen. If I use a "seen" array won't that again give me O(m* n) SC?

Please ignore the call to "initializeGrid()" method, I am just using that to bring the grid back to the original state.

Comment: You don't need to keep track of all the history of visited states. Hint: the search always expands outwards -- so by knowing where you are, and where the starting point is, you can just expand to the next unvisited cells.

Comment: The search don't necessarily expand outwards, it seems that way because we are keeping track of the state. Otherwise it could expand inwards too without tracking the state.

Comment: The point is that you can optimize your implementation to only search expanding outwards. Of course, your current implementation does not have this property. But you can achieve it.